# Changing from joins to includes breaking query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, squeel

I had this working query:

```
@search = Availability.joins{facility.activities}
.where{activities.id == s_activity}
```

But my view was getting a lot of information from Facilities and this resulted in an N+1 issue.

So I decided I should be using `includes` instead to eager load my associations

```
@search = Availability.includes{facility.activities}
.where{ facility.activities.id == s_activity)}
```

But this results in an error:

```
!! #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "activities"
LINE 1: ...T "availabilities".* FROM "availabilities" WHERE ("activitie...
                                                             ^
```

These are the associations:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :facilities
end

class Availability < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Associations
  belongs_to :facility
end

class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  #  Associations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :activities
  has_many :availabilities

end
```

There's a table called `activities_facilities` for the `has_and_belongs_to_many`

Comment: I've tried different variations in the where clause but I get the same error

Comment: Try `Availability.includes(facility: [:activities]).where('facility.activities.id = ?', s_activity).references(:facility, :activities)`

Comment: Returns an error http://pastebin.com/09Aj7cX5

Comment: Can you try this `Availability.includes(facility: [:activities]).where('activities.id = ?', s_activity).references(:facility, :activities)` ?

Comment: Thanks, seems to work now. I was able to convert it to Squeel DSL and get `Availability.includes{facility.activities}.where{activities.id == 1}.references(:facility, :activities)` so the main difference in the `.references` . I have to look into what that does

Comment: I just read this in their documentation: `Includes works similarly with joins, it uses outer join defaultly. In Rails 4, you need to use references with includes together.` The answer was there all along -_-  Thanks a lot. If you submit as an answer ill give you the credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append `.references` when using `includes` with ***conditions***.

```
Availability.includes(facility: [:activities]).where('activities.id = ?', s_activity).references(:facility, :activities)
```

> If you want to add conditions to your included models you’ll have to
>   explicitly reference them

Refer ***conditions*** part in [***`includes`***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)